# Cypress Testing Library as open source

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I should be starting testing react soon, I am more focused on integration and e2e testing as unit testing will be done by developers. However we would like to respect some homogeneity in our react testing tool-kit. I am only interested into open source tools. I know that cypress is a good candidate for e2e testing however it's not open source. My question is is it possible to use cypress as a testing library instead : https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro and will it have any limitation compared to using cypress? Which runner would you recommend and will i need to bundle any other tool with the library?

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress Test Runner](https://www.cypress.io/pricing/#test-runner-and-dashboard-difference) (the core functionality that makes Cypress run) is open source. You can easily run Cypress in whatever CI you have set up at no cost (other than the CI cost)